# A "must" to write width and height on img tags?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Regarding this article: http://webdesign.about.com/cs/graphics/qt/tipimgrealsize.htm

and other articles I've read it's a "must" to write the width and height in img tags. But maybe this changes now, where Responsive WebDesign is deprecated, I guess?

So, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and found out troubles using a fixed width and height on img-tags. In my css I use:

```
width: 100%; height: auto
```

Then it's scales correctly on each device. But is the loading time or whatever significantly slower when I'm not providing width and height values of the image? Furthermore, is there another way to solve this like it's meant to be with Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: It seems to me that you're asking the wrong question.  You've asked "is X necessary?" when you've observed a downside by not doing X.  It would have been more beneficial to ask how you can fix your implementation of X.  By asking "is X necessary?", all you're getting is opinionated answers that don't address the actual problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I'd specify it on the element for desktop views, but for responsive views override with the code you have suggested. Also make sure you put `display: block` on there. That helps IE out when you are doing this responsive shrinking ;)

The reason width/height attributes help is it means the browser can lay the page out before the image has loaded, otherwise you get a 'jump' effect.

It **is** a must to resize your images to the maximum size you will be displaying them. There is no reason your users should download extra bytes just for the browser to resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is said you should give image height/width is that; browser render height/width before image so keeps a vacant container on the site before loading of image...so structure of the website don't disturbs while loading the website.

Well. when i use to create responsive layout through media queries i use same tech. But for the smaller devices according to my experience its not wise to re-size (through CSS) same big image for smaller devices. So, what i use a re-sized smaller version of images for smaller devices for fast load... so it make the site pretty fast to load relatively.

Other technique you can use to optimize image for web by some tool like Photoshop this will improve the speed also as image size will go down a lot by this.

last but not the least optimized your code as well remove unnecessary tags & css.

good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Not a must. And, as you yourself have explained, is not appropriate for responsive pages. The browser does make use of the width/height so there is a performance hit but it is usually worth it for the sake of responsiveness.

Comment: Anyone reading your answer without knowing what "responsiveness" is really referring to is in for quite the irony.

Comment: @BoltClock Could you explain?

Comment: @Cruncher: It's a joke (a pretty lame one I'll admit). Before [the original RWD writeup](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design), "responsiveness" usually meant UI responsiveness, which means it was a performance-related term. Now, only in web design, "responsiveness" means something *totally* different and unrelated to performance. Here the answer is talking about sacrificing performance for the sake of "responsiveness", which doesn't make sense to the uninitiated.